# Accessing node's full path in graphene middleware

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django, graphql-python

I am trying to add some logging to my graphene server utilizing a middleware. As per the documentation ([Docs - 3.2.3](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/graphene-python/stable/graphene-python.pdf)), I can view some limited path info from the parent by pulling out the name from the root's meta node (`root._meta.name` which will result in Ex. `Three.Four`), but I am looking to get the full path of the current node being resolved (`One.Two.Three.Four`). Is there any way to access this info through the middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `info.path` to get this.